# Как программно включить скролл у TextView?

Tags: android, android-textview

Добавляю на активность LinearLayout, ScrollView и TextView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</ScrollView>
```

После установки кастомной ширины/высоты TextView перестает скроллиться.

```
textView.setMaxHeight(x);
```

Как вернуть возможность скролла?

Comment: попробуйте `myTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

Comment: welcome) отметьте, что "ответ получен"

Answer (score 3):

используйте `myTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`